# SSL Connection timeout and read timeouts

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, settimeout, connection-timeout

I have a doubt on where to set the socket timeout within my code. What I am trying to achieve is that when the socket is created the timeout should be 10seconds. So I am setting it before the handshake. now the error that I see in the logs are of two kinds. 1) Connection Timeout Error and 2) Read timeout Error. So I was wondering if anyone could explain me more about where to set the timeouts. I have the following code:

```
try{
  SSLSocketFactory factory=(SSLSocketFactory)SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
  socket = (SSLSocket)factory.createSocket(host,port);
  socket.setSoTimeout(10000);
  socket.startHandshake();

  OutputStream socketOut =( socket.getOutputStream() );

  String command = method+" "+path+" HTTP/1.0\n";
  //command+="Host: "+host+"\nConnection: close\n";

  if (data!=null) {
command+="Content-Length: " + data.length +"\n\n";
    sendBytes.write(command.getBytes(),0,command.length());
    sendBytes.write(data,0,data.length);
  } else {
    // if data == null then we are most likely doing a GET request
    sendBytes.write(command.getBytes(),0,command.length());
  }

  sendBytes.write("\n".getBytes(),0,"\n".length());

  temp = sendBytes.toByteArray();
  socketOut.write(temp,0,temp.length);
  socketOut.flush();

  /* read response */
  BufferedInputStream socketIn = 
    new BufferedInputStream( socket.getInputStream() );

  byte[] inputData = new byte[READSIZE];
  while ((bytesRead=socketIn.read(inputData,0,READSIZE)) > -1) {
      receiveBytes.write(inputData,0,bytesRead);
  }
  result=receiveBytes.toByteArray();

  //receiveBytes.close();
  //sendBytes.close();
  //socket.close();

} catch (Exception e) {
  throw e;
}finally {
try { receiveBytes.close(); sendBytes.close(); socket.close(); } catch (Exception ee) {}
}     
return result;
} // end submit

} // end class
```

Please  let me know how can i get the timeout to atleast work . In the logs the errors are occuring at 18secs ( which should not be the case) instead of 10secs.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The problem is most likely that the timeout already occurs upon connection when creating your socket. Try instantiating an unconnected socket first with the no arguments factory method and then use [Socket#connect](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#connect%28java.net.SocketAddress,%20int%29) with the `timeout` option in addition to `Socket#setSoTimeout`. The latter only kicks in for these operations

> ServerSocket.accept()
>
> SocketInputStream.read()
>
> DatagramSocket.receive()

but does not handle timeouts during connection attempts.

See also the [technical article for networking timeouts](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Networking/timeouts/) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the input . I will implement this in the code. The other thing that concerns me is that what if the handshake() went through fine, does the socket.setSoTimeout(10000) work for the read and write operations ???

Comment: @Jassi yes it does. 10 seconds is rather short for a read timeout; you need to make sure it only catches failure cases. I would generally set it to a minute or two.